# Get like_count & comments_count for specific media with Facebook Instagram API business_discovery

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I would like to update the like_count and comments_count for a specific instagram post with the new Facebook Instagram API. We have the post id and other data stored in our database and would only need the data of that specific post. At this point I am able to get the like and comment count via this API call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/xxxx?fields=business_discovery.username(jacqehoward){id,name,username,website,profile_picture_url,biography,followers_count,media_count,media.after(QVFIUlZA5aTR5NTE4Y24tNW90VGZAPTVBtb0NpOEFPTlNLeklmVTEtUDZAfVnE0YnBhUVNOQ3BDaktzNHJBTENhTmVYLUV2SGJPZAVAxZA09hQ2NhUGdnUGFjMTNn){id,caption,comments_count,like_count,media_type,media_url,owner,timestamp}}
```

After a while new posts are added to the account and you would need to go through all of the posts to find them again and to be able to get the like & comments count. In the old Instagram API you could get like and comment count per media. In the new Instagram API you are only able to get reach or "engagement" which is a combination of likes and comments while I want to have them separately. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/insights

Anyone who has an idea how to add like count and comments count to the insight endpoint call?

Second question: If an instagram user with a private instagram account connects with your app how do you get the Facebook instagram ID so you can collect the posts on their timeline?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/ …?

Comment: So where would you add the media post id in the request to get the number of likes for that post? In the example they only the latest media vs specific media or am I missing something?

Comment: That was in reference to “In the old Instagram API you could get like and comment count per media.” No sure whether there is a way to combine this with the request you have above, maybe vie Field Expansion syntax.

Comment: That was what I was hoping too, but I can't find any documentation about it or example on SO. It would make sense it's possible.